# How to query bin level LUT on Aerospike 5.5?

Tags: aerospike

Assume you have a set as follows:

```
+-------+-------+
| PK    | myBin |
+-------+-------+
| "1" |  24    |
+-------+-------+
1 row in set (1 secs)
```

How to get the LUT metadata for `PK=1` for bin `myBin`?

**NOTE**: I'm looking for `bin` level LUT and not row level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bin-level LUTs are not exposed to the clients due to backward compatibility reasons. So, you cannot query them from client. Also, bin-level LUTs are not always maintained. They are maintained only under certain XDR configurations.

A work around is to write an additional bin with the time stamp of the update along with the regular bin update. If you have few bins for which you need to know the update time stamp, this is a reasonable workaround with some overhead.

Comment: Thanks @sunil, is it possible programmatically via the Java client? I saw discussing that in Aerospike 5.5 it supported

Comment: It is true that it is maintained under certain configuration of XDR in 5.5. But it is not exposed to any clients.

Comment: So is there some way to find the LUT of a specific bin in some other way? since the work around you suggested is very memory-waste for my use, in general i'm trying to recover corrupted data that uploaded from Kafka, the recovery process first pause the upload process to AS, then save the current AS machine time and then re-create the upload process and then truncate all the records on which LUT <= that current time recorded. thats recovery can fail on multi bins writtes from multi uploaders (if they will run 1 by 1) and the bin-level LUT solve it but i see its not exposed

Comment: Like record LUT, bin-level LUTs are also not exposed to the Aerospike clients. Further, bin-level LUTs are not even accessible via User Defined Functions that you can write in LUA and run on server nodes. Only record level LUT is accessible via UDFs.  In other words, there is no way for a user to do any operations based on bin-level LUTs. They are only internally accessible to the cross data center replication module of Aerospike.